# C# MVC HTML.Textbox with Bootstrap appearance/action

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textbox that when the user enters a string and presses a button this is then compared to find which matching fields are in database. I also have another button that launches the display of a bootstrap modal which then views the results.

The issue I'm having is I only want one button but when I try to combine the two i get the modal and the string search never happens.

Can anyone tell me how I combine the two ?

Button 1 (search string button)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    <label for="platform" class="control-label">Enter Code:</label><br />
                   @Html.TextBox("filtername")
                    <input type="submit" value="Filter" "/>
                </p>
            }
```

Button 2 (Activates modal but no data comparision)

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                    <div class="span7 text-center">                           
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="theCode" placeholder="Please Enter Code">                                
                        <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="btn btn-success" id="sendcoderequest" data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="#basicModal2" />                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Home/Index Method:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string filtername)        
    {

        var filterresults = from m in db.UserInfoes
                            select m;            

        filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.UserCode.ToString().Contains(filtername)).OrderBy(x => x.UserCode);

        return View(filterresults);
    }
```

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Summary</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h2>Results</h2>
                                <span id="printCode"></span><br />

                                <div class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="toggle">Toggle</button> </div>

                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Test Type</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checks">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppModeId)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Code currently working with:
Form:

```
<form id="formid">
  <label for="platform" class="control-label">Enter Code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="filtername" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
 $("#formid").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#modal_content').html(response);
            $('#basicModal2').modal('show');
        });
        return false; // prevent the form submission
    });
```

Modal is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX call instead of the form submission. Then you could open the modal via Javascript once you receive the AJAX response. According to the tags, you're probably using JQuery, so it would look like this :

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "Home",
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function(response){
      // Fill your modal window with the response here
      $('#basicModal2').modal('show');
  });
  return false; // prevent the form submission
});
```

**Edit**

You can find here an example that uses AJAX to send the filter name to the server, fill the modal with the server response and finally show the modal: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yohanrobert/e3p4yv55/

Comment: Hi Groyoh I tried using the above code in <script> tags like normal jquery and it had no effect. I'm pretty new to jquery but from what i understand this will effect all forms on this page ?

Comment: Yes this will affect all form but you could simply add an `id`to the form tag and use the JQuery selector on that form.
Did you make sure to put the script tag after the JQuery one?

Comment: I cant seam to make the above solution work sorry, i added changed $("form").submit to $("#formid").submit and <form> to <form id="formid"> but on clicking submit button the modal isn't being launched. Ive added my modal above if this is any help ?

Comment: Well, the AJAX call might not be successful then. Did you check it?
And did you use the code above or did you add anything to it?

Comment: Hi Groyoh Ive added the code I'm working with above so you can see my changes. I'm unsure about the line where you had // Fill your modal window with the response here Ive just used the code from the fiddle but I'm guessing this is wrong? I'm an AJAX noob :)